# viewWillAppear equivilent in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, viewwillappear

Is there an equivalent method to viewWillAppear (iOS) for Windows Phone 8?

Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere, I've had a good look around!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the onNavigated to method as explained in the link below. This worked just fine

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedto%28v=vs.95%29.aspx